# sbt-release publish tar.gz

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-release

I want to use [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) to publish tar.gz file to our artifactory server, I followed the code in[google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/Td389FbdgCY/lRzEon2inIIJ),but they are using zip artifact. I need the tar.gz due to file permissions in linux. How to achieve this in sbt-release?

Comment: Take a look into sbt-native-packager

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this?